# How to open react select menu pragmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to open react select menu on click of a button.

here is the link of code sand box

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-kssrb

I know a react select property 'menuIsOpen', Drawback of this prop is menu is always open and default close behaviour is lost because of this.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along with *menuIsOpen* prop, you are also going to need the **onBlur** event to make it mork.

As *menuIsOpen* prop does reset all the on-* events for the Select component.

Additionally for **onBlur** to work, you need to  set the focus to the dropdown element using **setFocus**.

You can check this out over here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-gxvxr

Answer (score 5):

You can try and use storing a ref to the component, calling a `.focus()` on it.
And pass to the React Select prop `openMenuOnFocus`.

Sample on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-hooks-forked-qol5m

Short essence:

```
  const selectRef = useRef();
  const onClick = () => {
    selectRef.current.focus();
  };

    <Dropdown
      openMenuOnFocus={true}
      ref={selectRef}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today, `react-select` does not allow you to go to next focusable elements of the interface using the keyboard. It blocks the 'TAB' key, when you set `openMenuOnFocus=true`. In this case, in my opinion, the best method is to call the MouseEvent in combination with useRef (selectRef):

```js
const synteticEvent = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
  view: window,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
});

selectRef.current.controlRef.dispatchEvent(synteticEvent);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just make the value of "menuIsOpen" false once the user selects anything from the select box

See this. I have made the necessary changes

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-guo4i

Comment: Default close behaviour is lost because of this approach. I just want to trigger menu open and user can close this by tabbing out or by clicking outer area

Comment: I gave you an example on how that can be done. You can add more to it. You can use onBlur/onFocus to achieve what you need.